# Align/position header image background correctly

Tags: html, css, image, background, position

I am currently working on a site and have a problem with aligning/positioning the background image in the main header area.

I want the image to be fully seen there. And I want it also to work when I scale down to mobile versions of the site.

Here is a screenshot of the problem, the image is just centred (I also have used larger images):

[image: Header Image]

Below is my CSS code:

```
.header-six .header-t {
    padding: 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("/image.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `background-size: cover`?

On w3schools is defined as:

> "Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges"

Recommended to take a look at the description page of `background-size` to understand better how to use it properly: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: it actually worked! just needed `background-size: cover` and  `background-position: center` thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.header-six .header-t {    
width: 100%;}
```

This might help.

Comment: unfortenately no effect